# Eliminating word noise while editing a questions

Tags: discussion, questions

By word noise I mean posts like.

> Hi all you gurus,
>   <question here>?
>   thanks,
>   -joe somebody

If I've already opened the question for editing, poor grammar and whatnot, should I eliminate the word noise?

It seems a no brainer, except there are more subjective cases like

> Man! I've looked everywhere and google comes up with nothing.
>   How does <question-here>?

I would normally say the first line is just noise, but there some question where the noise actually helps make the question a little more understandable.

Answer (score 3):

Remove them.  [There's precedence for this.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

If it adds nothing to the question at all, feel free to remove it.  It can only improve the quality of the site as a whole.

Signatures are completely unnecessary since we have those little flair boxes.  "Hi" doesn't do anything.

Generally I won't remove them unless I'm editing the question for other reasons anyway, though.

Comment: However, if the user rolls back to keep their signature, one should respect that wish, as [stated here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/2960#2960). No point in edit-wars for minor reasons